# I transfered ERC-20 token to the wrong Efinity address

Tags: cpp-ethereum, polkadot

I transfered ERC-20 token to the wrong Efinity(NFT blockchain on Polkadot) address,how to get it back? Someone plz let me know

Comment: Im afraid you cant do that. Only way is having the person/entity in control of that address send the tokens back to you.

Answer (score 0):

If this address exists and you know who it belongs to, you can ask nicely to send it back.
Otherwise there is not way (except if you can pull of an 51% attack).
Blockchain is designed do be permanent, otherwise how could you trust any payment you receive?

Comment: thanks man,i got it back through exchange platform